# Ubuntu / SVN Command Line Launches Emacs

Tags: svn

I just did an `svn delete` via command line. It worked successfully, but then launched me into Emacs, where I had to exit, and then hit "c" to continue.

I am not really and Emacs guy, and tend to use vi in the shell.

Is there a way to avoid what seems to me is a clumsy process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your [EDITOR environment variable](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaleditors.html) to the editor you want to use, or provide the commit message on the command line:

```
svn delete -m "deleting file whatever" whatever
```